# What is the technical difference of ST14000NM001G and ST14000NM0018?

Tags: hard-drive

I looked in to the web and seagate site, they both got the same capacity, speed, cache, and all. One is from x16 and the other is from x14 model.

However, other than that, what is the actual technical differences of both seagate drives?

Comment: Data sheet for the ..18 https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/exos-x-14-channel-DS1974-4-1812US-en_US.pdf and the data sheet for the ..1G https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/exos-x16-DS2011-1-1904US-en_GB.pdf

Comment: Random Read/Write 4K QD16 WCD (IOPS) is higher on the ..1G drive, 170/440 vs 170/418

Comment: Oh, yes, that is what I missed, btw, is x14 a reject version of exos drive? its not that visible from seagate exos page.

Comment: No idea. You'd have to ask Seagate about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random Read/Write 4K QD16 WCD (IOPS) is higher on the ST14000NM001G drive, 170/440 vs 170/418 on the ST14000NM0018 drive.